# How to check if the element has multiple css class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some html like below. I have loop through the all the elements inside the div(accordionContents).Inside the loop i need to check a condition if the element h2 has applying two css class(acc_trigger and active) or not.How can i do it?

```
 <div id="accordionContents">
     <div class="accordioncontainer">         
                    <h2 class="acc_trigger active">
                       <a href="#"> <img class="openImage" src="Images/closed.png"> 
                          <div class="openHeader">Division : <b>Quality Assurance</b>(4 items)</div></a></h2>
                    <div class="acc_container" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="dataRowTeam">
                            <div class="riskStartContent">
                                <div class="riskGridHeader">
                                    weekStart</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="riskEndContent">
                                <div class="riskGridHeader">
                                    90%</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                 <div class="accordioncontainer">


                    <h2 class="acc_trigger">
                       <a href="#"> <img class="openImage" src="Images/closed.png"> 
                        <div class="openHeader">Division : <b>Quality Assurance</b>(4 items)</div></a></h2>
                    <div class="acc_container" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="dataRowTeam">
                            <div class="riskStartContent">
                                <div class="riskGridHeader">
                                    weekStart</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="riskEndContent">
                                <div class="riskGridHeader">
                                    90%</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the jQuery code which contains your loop.

Comment: i didn't write that code. because i don't know how to check that condtion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific case this should be quite enough:

```
var hasActive = $('.acc_trigger').hasClass("active"); // Bool. TRUE / FALSE

if(hasActive){
    // do something if TRUE
}
```

Otherwise you can go directly for *element existence*

```
$('.acc_trigger.active').css({background: 'red'});
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/imabuc/1/edit)**</kbd>

BTW, your HTML formatting is quite unusual, I'd rather say wrong:
`DIV` (block-level elements) are not supposed to be found inside `A` (inline) elements

Comment: after checking how can i apply  a css to a img tag  only the h2 element has two css class?

Comment: inside the loop i need to apply the css. for example Inside that accordion Content div has more than one accordion container div.Inside this div has h2 element.this h2 element has more than one css i can to apply css to the img tag only.

Comment: just as i mentioned in my comment: addClass is what you need

Comment: @JEMI `$('.acc_trigger.active').find('img').addClass('someImageClass')`

Answer (score 0):

just try to ask hasClass more than once ;)

```
$(".accordionContents").each(function(){
    var $headline = $("h2", this).first();
    var hasBothCSSClasses = $headline.hasClass('acc_trigger') & $headline.hasClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You can put multiple classes inside `hasClass()` E.g. `.hasClass('acc_trigger active')`: http://jsfiddle.net/wU8FJ/

Comment: after checking How can i apply css to image tag inside that container only the h2 has two css class?

Comment: thats easy, just call .addClass() on the found image
`if(hasBothCSSClasses) $("img", this).addClass('myspecialClass');`

Comment: @JEMI I don't have the big picture here, but judging from what you  said there, I think you might be fine just using css: `.acc_trigger.active { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jH8RF/1/

```
var clslen = $('h2').attr('class').split(' ').join(',');
var len = clslen.indexOf(',');

if( len > 0){
     alert('elem has more than one class');
}else{
     alert('elem has just one class');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.accordionContents h2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.acc_trigger.active')) {
        // do something...
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var strValue = $("h2").prop('class').trim();
if(strValue.indexOf(" ") > -1)
{
    //This element has multiple classes.
}
else
{
    //This element has a single class.
}
```