# jQuery count of specific class an element contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and each row in the table has one or more classes depending on the region.

Here is what my table looks like:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="emea apac">
        <td>Testing</td>
        <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="americas">
        <td>Testing2</td>
        <td>Jim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emea">
        <td>Testing 3</td>
        <td>Kyle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emea americas">
        <td>Testing 3</td>
        <td>Kyle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emea apac americas">
        <td>Testing 3</td>
        <td>Kyle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="apac">
        <td>Testing 3</td>
        <td>Kyle</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to now count specifically how many rows there are where the class is equal to my condition.

For example:

How many rows have ONLY `.APAC` = 1

How many rows have all 3 of the possible classes? = 1

I started this jsFiddle but couldn't really think of how to approach it from this point: http://jsfiddle.net/carlhussey/gkywznnj/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from your fiddle ([updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gkywznnj/5/))...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var apac = 0,
        emea = 0,
        americas = 0,
        combo = 0,
        all = 0;
    $('table tbody tr').each(function (i, elem) {
        var classes = elem.className.split(' '),
            hasApac = classes.indexOf('apac') > -1,
            hasEmea = classes.indexOf('emea') > -1,
            hasAmericas = classes.indexOf('americas') > -1;
        apac += (hasApac && !hasEmea && !hasAmericas) ? 1 : 0;
        emea += (hasEmea && !hasApac && !hasAmericas) ? 1 : 0;
        americas += (hasAmericas && !hasApac && !hasEmea) ? 1 : 0;
        if (((hasApac && hasEmea) || (hasApac &&  hasAmericas) || (hasEmea && hasAmericas)) && classes.length === 2) {
            combo += 1;
        }
        if (hasApac && hasEmea &&  hasAmericas) {
            all += 1;
        }
    });
    $('span[name="apac"]').text(apac);
    $('span[name="emea"]').text(emea);
    $('span[name="americas"]').text(americas);
    $('span[name="combo"]').text(combo);
    $('span[name="all"]').text(all);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I'm pretty sure jQuery's [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method works with IE8, so you could change the `.each` callback to:

```
function (i, elem) {
    var row = $(elem),
        hasApac = row.hasClass('apac'),
        hasEmea = row.hasClass('emea'),
        hasAmericas = row.hasClass('americas');
    apac += (hasApac && !hasEmea && !hasAmericas) ? 1 : 0;
    emea += (hasEmea && !hasApac && !hasAmericas) ? 1 : 0;
    americas += (hasAmericas && !hasApac && !hasEmea) ? 1 : 0;
    if (((hasApac && hasEmea) || (hasApac &&  hasAmericas) || (hasEmea && hasAmericas)) && elem.className.split(' ').length === 2) {
        combo += 1;
    }
    if (hasApac && hasEmea &&  hasAmericas) {
        all += 1;
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkywznnj/6/

Comment: Amazing, just want I needed. I thought there may have been a more dynamic way to do this but this is working and just what I needed. Thanks, Pete!

Comment: I know I forgot to mention this but it wasnt until I tried it... I get an error on IE8 (required use) with the lines containing indexOf. Are those not compatible ? Any idea for a work around?

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = $('tr'),
    class = 'americas',
    counter = 0;
rows.each(function () {
//If current element have .americas increment counter
   if($(this).hasClass(class)) {
       counter +=1    
   }
});
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: hasClass includes all rows that have that class. I need to be more specific. I need to say how many rows ONLY have americas as the class; not how many rows contain americas

Comment: So you can combine this script with

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771521/how-to-check-if-the-element-has-multiple-css-class-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gkywznnj/8/

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

function countOnlyClass(classFindA)
{
    var $trA=$('table tbody tr');
    var count=0; 

    if(classFindA.length>0){

        $trA.each(function(){

            var c=0;    
            var m=0;
            var $tr=$(this);
            var classA = $tr.attr('class').split(' ');

            $.each(classA,function(i,cl){
                if(classFindA.indexOf(cl)>-1) c++; else m++;
            })

            if(c>0 && c==classFindA.length && m==0) count++;

        })
    }        

    return count;
}    

function comboOnlyClass(comboCount)
{
    var $trA=$('table tbody tr');
    var count=0; 

    $trA.each(function(){

        var countClass = {};

        var $tr=$(this);
        var classA = $tr.attr('class').split(' ');

        $.each(classA,function(i,cl){
            if(!cl in countClass )             
                countClass.cl=1;
        })

        if(Object.size(classA )==comboCount) count++;

    })

    return count;
}

var a=countOnlyClass(['apac'])
$('#apac').html(a);

var a=countOnlyClass(['emea'])
$('#emea').html(a);

var a=countOnlyClass(['americas'])
$('#americas').html(a);

var a=countOnlyClass(['apac','emea','americas'])
$('#all').html(a);

var a=comboOnlyClass(2);
$('#combo').html(a);

//var a=comboOnlyClass(1); onlu one class
```